# cmd + space opening new windows using Magic keyboard

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth

I'm not entirely sure when this issue started, it could have been after upgrading to Mojave, but again, not sure. I have upgraded to Catalina hoping it would fix it, but nope.

Whenever I press cmd + space to launch spotlight, the os tries to open a new window for the current app on focus. If I'm using chrome a new window opens up, if I'm navigating finder, a new finder window pops up.

While I was writing this question, the same issue happened but I don't think I hit cmd at all, it might have been a combination of a different key + space.

Have tried factory resetting the keyboard, resetting bluetooth module, even tested on a different macbook, same issue.